# dynamic import's on.("click", ...) can't find global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I am trying to create an application in electron (code in front end javascript side) to aid in my writing, and something I *need* is to dynamically load modules/plugins/mods. I am able to actually import a function that has a class returned from it (It was the only way so far that I could actually get dynamic import of a class to work...), and it assigns some jquery node.on("click") that do not run as expected. I have several object containers that I use to separate major portions of my code from any by chance matching variables. Anyways, the one for menus (MenuManager) throws an error that it cannot be found when I click the element for on("click").

I want the variables like MenuManager to be globally available inside the app, so plugins/mods can make any decided changes.

MenuManager.js

```js
//Isolate MenuManager variables to itself, to majorly reduce variable naming mishaps and make it
//easier to modify something later
let MenuManager = {
    menus: []
}

//import PluginDef from "../../Workspaces/Writing/define.js";

$(function () {
    console.log("MenuManager Booting!");

    //Create menus from plugin
    LoadPlugins();
    LoadPlugins();
});

function LoadPlugins() {
    /*const testLoad = import("../../Workspaces/Writing/define.js");
    console.log(testLoad.default.PluginDef().Name);*/

    import("../../Workspaces/Writing/define.js").then((module) => {
        let newModule = module.default();
        newModule.Generate();
        MenuManager.menus.push(newModule);
        console.log("loading: " + MenuManager.menus[0].Name);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

imported define.js

```js
export default function PluginDef() {
    class def {
        constructor() {
            this.Name = "Writing";
            this.MenuBase = "<h5>Menus HTML here</5>";//import from file later
            this.workspaceBase = "<h5>Workspace HTML here</h5>";//import from file later
        }
        Generate() {
            this.GenerateSelector();
            this.GenerateMenu();
            this.GenerateWorkspace();
            this.Run_OnGenerated();
        }

        GenerateSelector() {
            let Self = this;
            //Generate Menu Selector Header
            this.menuSelector = $([
                "<li>",
                this.Name,
                "</li>"
            ].join("\n"));

            //Add listener to selector
            this.menuSelector.on("click", function () {
                //let foundMenu = MenuManager.menus.find(x => x.Name == this.textContent);
                MenuManager.currentMenu.menu.removeClass("selectedMenu");
                MenuManager.currentMenu.workspace.removeClass("selectedWorkPanel");
                MenuManager.currentMenu.Run_OnClose();//Ran whenever menu is deselected

                MenuManager.currentMenu = Self;//Set 'this' to currently selected menu
                MenuManager.currentMenu.menu.addClass("selectedMenu");
                MenuManager.currentMenu.workspace.addClass("selectedWorkPanel");
                MenuManager.currentMenu.Run_OnOpen();//Ran whenever menu is selected
            });

            //Add selector to header
            AppPart.MenuBarSelector.find("ul").append(this.menuSelector);
        }

        GenerateMenu() {
            //Generate Menu
            this.menu = $([
                "<div id='Menu_Writing' class='menuBarPanel'>",
                this.MenuBase,
                "</div>"
            ].join("\n"));
            //Add menu to panels
            AppPart.MenuBarOptionsContainer.append(this.menu);
        }

        GenerateWorkspace() {
            //Generate Workspace
            this.workspace = $([
                "<div id='WorkPanel_Writing' class='workPanel'>",
                this.workspaceBase,
                "</div>"
            ].join("\n"));
            //Add workspace to workspace
            AppPart.WorkAreaContainer.append(this.workspace);
        }

        //When menu is generated, run this function
        Run_OnGenerated() {
            return;//does nothing
        }

        //When menu is selected, run this function
        Run_OnOpen() {
            return;//Does Nothing
        }

        //When menu is deselected, run this function
        Run_OnClose() {
            return;//Does Nothing
        }
    }

    return new def();
}
```

GenerateSelector() of imported define.js (line 27 specifically) is where the error for `MenuManager is not defined` happens

Comment: Put the MenuManager variable in a separate script and export it. Then import it in the scripts that need it. Just use the exact same mechanism you're using when you import PluginDef. If this won't work for dynamically imported scripts, you can try `global.MenuManger = { ... };` and use that in other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see @Chris G's comment/answer, because I did not get an email or such. But anyways, I had figured out through I think blind luck that:

I could create a base class and place that in window, where the imported class could easily access the class without trying to remember or know any file locations (And yes, I am working on keeping global/window clean, not shoving it with tons of variables, just the few important ones like this case)

Note: I cannot explain why this exactly works, but possibly due to the scope.

MenuManager.js

```js
function LoadPlugins() {
    import("../../Workspaces/Writing/define.js").then((module) => {
        let newModule = module.default();
        MenuManager.menus.push(newModule);
        console.log("loaded: " + MenuManager.menus[0].Name);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}



class PluginBaseDef {
    Name;
    MenuBase;
    workspaceBase;

    menuSelector;
    menu;
    workspace;

    constructor() {
    }

    Generate() {
        this.GenerateSelector();
        this.GenerateMenu();
        this.GenerateWorkspace();
        this.Run_OnGenerated();

        if (!MenuManager.currentMenu.Name) {
            this.ShowMenu();
        }
    }
}

window.PluginBaseDef = PluginBaseDef;
```

imported define.js

```js
export default function PluginDef() {
    class def extends window.PluginBaseDef {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.Name = "Writing";
            this.MenuBase = "<h5>Menus HTML here</5>";//import from file later
            this.workspaceBase = "<h5>Workspace HTML here</h5>";//import from file later
            this.Generate();
        }
    }
    return new def();
}
```